# MBSTRING issue: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, centos, cpanel

Error message on frontend:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning
Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.so' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Filename: Unknown
Line Number: 0
Backtrace:
```

I'm using a development team from India for a new platform
everything was OK when they use their own server but now they migrate the website on my VPS Centos 6.9 with PHP7 
now seems to be an issue with the mbstring extension, I already check under 
"php -m" and the extensions mbstring and exif are here and same under "php --ini"

on the php.ini file I comment out extension_dir and the extensions themselves 
(see that in several posts) but still issue is here 
I will appreciate any help cause I'm not a server guy and the team I'm working with not really help with that,m thanks

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/02-pecl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-imap.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-json.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/php_exif.ini,
/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d/php_mbstring.ini
```

on php.ini file

```
; extension_dir = "ext"
;extension=php_mbstring.so
;extension=php_exif.so
```

Comment: If you commented out the extensions, then they are disabled. Remove the  semicolon to enable them.
Additionally, you should use a more descriptive title to for this post and not an error message. Make sure to edit your question and include the error message, though.

Comment: I'm using easy apache 4 and from other posts with same issue it was supposed to solve the problem, anyway even if I remove the semicolon it's the same. it's looks like it's searching the extension in the wrong place

Comment: in /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules instead of /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.d

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it
I just remove the old PHP versions 5.5 and 5.6 and now the error is gone :)

```
yum remove ea-php55*
yum remove ea-php56*
```

restart apache and php-fpm  and everything is working